# why my google analytics are inconsistent (permanent redirect)?

Tags: google-analytics

I moved one site to another domain with permanent redirection but session count are inconsistent.

On old domain sessions are increases:
[image]

but on new domain session count fluctuates:

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try filtering the reports by Hostname, to see what's happening to the traffic.

Set up a custom report that displays sessions by hostname.